# Exposing docker container ports not working

Tags: docker, spring-boot, port, dockerfile

I am having trouble exposing a port from a docker container to my server.
Here is what I've done:

I wrote a very simple spring boot app that runs on port 8080.
Now I am trying to deploy it into a docker container on my server.
Based on the [Spring - Getting started with Docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/#_containerize_it) Userguide I've created the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

In a second step I copied my jar to the same directory (where the dockerfile is stored) and built the container with the following command:

```
docker build . -t testportmapping --build-arg JAR_FILE=swagger-v2-person-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Now when I run:

```
docker run -d testportmapping:latest -p 9065:8080
```

The command runs without an error. But if I take a look at: `docker container ls`: I see that no portmapping was created:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED               STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
f15639c81903        testportmapping:latest   "java -Djava.securit…"   About 6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes                              mystifying_payne
```

**Does anyone know that I am doing wrong?**

#### What I've tried so far:

1. Using different local port
2. Adding an EXPOSE to the Dockerfile
3. Addinng `--net=host` to the `docker run` command
4. Running the container attached to see if the app starts up correctly (it does)

#### My setup:

```
root@jupiter /h/n/d/p/swagger-v2# docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        e68fc7a
 Built:             Tue Aug 21 17:24:56 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
  Engine:
  Version:          18.06.1-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       e68fc7a
  Built:            Tue Aug 21 17:23:21 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false


root@jupiter /h/n/d/p/swagger-v2# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run below command

```
docker run -d -p 9065:8080 testportmapping:latest
```

Image name should be the last parameters and all other parameters should come before it.

P.S. 
As mentioned by @David Maze in the comments, whatever comes after the image name is passed on to the container

Comment: (Anything after the image name is interpreted as the command to run in the container.)

Comment: You've made me facepalm so hard and saved hours of googling. Thanks a lot!